# Not able to sent mail through gmail SMTP in Azure server

Tags: c#, email, azure, smtp, gmail

My code is working on other domain and as well as local. but when I try to send mail through Azure server it's not working.
I look almost all helping link in stack overflow but still, it's not working.

I am using this thing

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("xyzanjyr@gmail.com", "***********");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

i am getting this exception

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm\r\n   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Comment: copy and paste the exception, please

Comment: i have update question plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use this code before sent mail it's working fine.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```